# How do I configure default application font in CentOS live CD?

Tags: linux, fonts, centos, live-cd

I have an application which runs on top of CentOS 7.3 live CD. I want to configure font while building the liveCD so that my application should pick that font as default font.

PS: the live cd is being made by someone else and I have to just configure the font in it.

Comment: What the heck linux-kernel tag is doing here?

Comment: If there's any kernel level API i can make use of